# Unshorten Google Links

Tags: code-golf, internet

## Challenge

Given a valid `goo.gl` shortened link, output the original URL.

## Example

`goo.gl/qIwi3N` would give something like `https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/`. For input, you can choose to have the `https?://` at the beginning, you can choose to have `www.` before the `goo.gl`, and you can also choose to get rid of the `goo.gl` if you only want the end of the URL. A slash at the end is optional for input and output. So, your input will end up matching the regex `(https?://)?(www\.)?(goo\.gl/)?[A-Za-z0-9]+/?`. For the output, you can choose whether or not to output `https?://`, whether or not to output `www.`, and whether or not to output a trailing slash. However, **you must be consistent with your I/O formatting**.

I will say that you do not have to be consistent with `https` vs. `http` for output (but you must be consistent for input), as long as you are consistent with whether or not you include the whole `https?://` part.

## Test Cases

These are written with no `https://`, no `www.`, no trailing slash in the input; yes `https://`, no `www.`, and yes trailing slash in the output.

```
input -> output
goo.gl/HaE8Au -> https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/
goo.gl/IfZMwe -> https://stackoverflow.com/
goo.gl/JUdmxL -> https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte
```

## Assumptions

- You may assume that the shortened link will not point to another shortened link and that the destination site will return a status code of `2xx` or `4xx` (no redirections).

You can go here and enter a URL to apply the inverse operation of this: https://goo.gl/

Comment: @HelkaHomba fixed

Comment: Weather or notr to output a leading `www.` makes a difference. It is just in most cases the same server it refers to. Try for example `http://pks.mpg.de` and `http://www.pks.mpg.de`. The first cannot be resolved, while the latter can.

Comment: @StephenS Done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 11):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
lg'"/5=
```

#### Test run

```
$ alias cjam
alias cjam='java -jar ~/.local/share/cjam-0.6.5.jar'
$ cjam unshorten.cjam <<< goo.gl/HaE8Au; echo
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/
$ cjam unshorten.cjam <<< goo.gl/IfZMwe; echo
https://stackoverflow.com/
$ cjam unshorten.cjam <<< goo.gl/JUdmxL; echo
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte
```

#### How it works

`lg` reads a line from STDIN and makes a GET request to that URL. The shortened URL issues a 301 redirect, which CJam doesn't follow. For the first test case, this pushes

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Permanently</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Permanently</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

on the stack. Finally, `'"/` splits at double quotes, and `5=` gets the sixth chunk. Output is implicit.

Comment: I've tried 05AB1E and Pyth, they both follow the 301 :(

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>28</s> 24 bytes

```bash
curl -I $1|grep -oehtt.*
```

The output ends with a Windows-style newline, which I assume is acceptable.

#### Test run

```
$ bash unshorten.sh 2>&- goo.gl/HaE8Au
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/
$ bash unshorten.sh 2>&- goo.gl/IfZMwe
https://stackoverflow.com/
$ bash unshorten.sh 2>&- goo.gl/JUdmxL
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte
```

#### How it works

`curl -I` sends a HEAD request, so it fetches only the HTTP headers of the specified URL. For the first test case, it prints

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Sat, 13 May 2017 05:51:48 GMT
Location: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

or similar. The output is piped to `grep -oehtt.*`, which displays only parts that match the specified regex, i.e., the string **htt** followed by any amount of characters up to the end of the line.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: Hehe, well explained! In that way i will learn bash soon :-D

Comment: This performs wildcard expansion on `htt.*` so assumes no files matching it exist in the current directory. For most regexes, I'd agree on this site that the possibility of a file being matched are small enough that it's okay, but in this case, I don't think so, myself. The Linux kernel source code includes files named `htt.c` and `htt.h`, for instance. Changing it to `grep -oehtt.*` does not increase the byte count, but does make it significantly less likely to cause problems.

Comment: @hvd I usually assume that the program is run in an otherwise empty directory, but `-oehtt.*` is a nice way to make it more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 + requests, 44 bytes

```python
from requests import*
print get(input()).url
```

`requests.get(URL)` issues a GET request to the specified URL. The response object's `url` field contains the final URL, after any redirects. A protocol (e.g. `http://`) is required for the input, and the input is expected to be in quotes.

Comment: `requests` isn't built-in, so that needs to be added to the language header.

Comment: Use a `lambda` expression for -3 bytes

Comment: @numbermaniac Whoops, you're right, I get so used to requests that I forget it's a third party lib.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 36 Bytes

Input with `https://`

```php
<?=substr(get_headers($argn)[7],10);
```

[get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

25 Bytes if `Location:`  at the beginning must not removed

```
<?=get_headers($argn)[7];
```

if Google changes the HTTP Header here is a safer version

```
preg_match("#Location: \K.*#",join("\n",get_headers($argn)),$t);echo$t[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

Has no dependencies and is currently shorter than the other Python answer. *shrug* Input must match `https?://goo\.gl/.*?/?`

```python
lambda s:urlopen(s).url
from urllib import*
```

Answer (score 0):

## NodeJS, 60 bytes

```
u=>require("http").get(u,r=>console.log(r.headers.location))
```

Input is in the format `http://goo.gl/<id>`.